# Populating a vector with random numbers

Tags: c++, random

I'll just dive right in: I was given a piece of code by my professor that's supposed to generate random numbers and my compiler (g++) keeps throwing these errors: "warning: pointer to a function used in arithmetic [-Wpointer-arith] rand[i]=((double) rand() / (static_cast(RAND_MAX) + 1.0))* (high - low) + low;"
"error: invalid cast from type 'std::vector' to type 'double' rand[i]=((double) rand() / (static_cast(RAND_MAX) + 1.0))* (high - low) + low;"
They both point to the function that generates the random numbers. The trouble is that I've used this exact same function before and it worked fine. I really have no idea what could be wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Note that I am still somewhat new to C++.

I've included: cstdlib, stdio.h, cstdio, time.h, vector, iomanip, fstream, iostream, cmath.
This is the code I have now:

```
int main() {
int N=20000;

std::srand((unsigned)time(0));

for(int i = 0; i<(N+1); ++i) {
    double high = 1.0, low = 0.0;
    rand[i]=((double) rand()/(static_cast<double>(RAND_MAX) + 1.0))*(high - low) + low;
    }

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Typo? The problem is `rand[i]` ... `rand` is a function not an array. Once you fix that you should be good.

Comment: indeed, you're using `rand` as both a function and an array

Comment: Related: If at all possible, seriously consider using the [`<random>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) library. [It really is the cat's whiskers](https://ideone.com/ZwfGQT).

Comment: Ah, thank you! Fixed, checked the numbers, and everything looks fine!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the name `rand` as both an array to write to and a standard library function you call. That's bad.

Declare an array with some other name, and write to it instead. Eg:

```
int main() {
  int N=20000;

  std::srand((unsigned)time(0));
  std::vector<double> A(N+1);

  for(int i = 0; i<(N+1); ++i) {
    double high = 1.0, low = 0.0;
    A[i]=((double) rand()/(static_cast<double>(RAND_MAX) + 1.0))*(high - low) + low;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked perfectly - checked the numbers as well and everything looks great. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

It really is time to move beyond rand. Here is a more modern version using features from  in C++11.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <random>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    const int n = 20000;

    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 e(rd());        // The random engine we are going to use

    const double low = 0.0;
    const double high = 1.0;

    std::uniform_real_distribution<double> urng(low, high);

    std::vector<double> A;
    std::generate_n(std::back_inserter(A), n + 1,
        [urng, &e](){ return urng(e); });

    return 0;
}
```